Debug Log not working with entity Sub scene (Unity, C#)
So I am working on a project that has a bunch of dynamic fog objects and I wanted to try and use DOTS for it, basically it is a ton of small sprites that shrink when the player approaches. I got all that working fine, and now I need to update the objects with the player's position.
I tried directly passing in the player's transform, but that didn't work, so I settled on passing a vector2. However, I was unable to update this vector2 in the authoring script or even debug.log I think this is due to the entity being in a sub scene or due to it being an entity, and now I'm looking for a fix.
FogAuthoring.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Unity.Entities;

using Unity.Mathematics;

using UnityEngine;

public class FogAuthoring : MonoBehaviour

{

public float LerpSpeed;

public float TargetScale;

public float2 PlayerPosition;

private Transform _player;

private void Start()

{

_player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;

Debug.Log("A");

}

private void Update()

{

PlayerPosition = new float2(_player.position.x, _player.position.y);

Debug.Log("B");

}

private class Baker : Baker<FogAuthoring>

{

public override void Bake(FogAuthoring authoring)

{

Entity entity = GetEntity(TransformUsageFlags.Dynamic);

AddComponent(entity, new FogData

{

LerpSpeed = authoring.LerpSpeed,

TargetScale = authoring.TargetScale,

PlayerPosition = authoring.PlayerPosition

});

}

}

}

public struct FogData : IComponentData

{

public float LerpSpeed;

public float TargetScale;

public float2 PlayerPosition;

}

FogControllerDOTS.cs
using System.Collections
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using Unity.Burst;

using Unity.Entities;

using Unity.Transforms;

using Unity.Jobs;

public partial struct FogControllerDOTS : ISystem

{

public const float distThreshold = 5;

public void OnCreate(ref SystemState state)

{

state.RequireForUpdate<FogData>();

}

[BurstCompile]

public void OnUpdate(ref SystemState state)

{

/*

foreach ((RefRW<LocalTransform> localTransform, RefRO<FogData> fogData) in SystemAPI.Query<RefRW<LocalTransform>, RefRO<FogData>>())

{

float currentScale = localTransform.ValueRO.Scale;

float targetScale;

if (Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(localTransform.ValueRO.Position.x, localTransform.ValueRO.Position.y), fogData.ValueRO.PlayerPosition) <= distThreshold)

targetScale = Mathf.Lerp(currentScale, 0, fogData.ValueRO.LerpSpeed * SystemAPI.Time.DeltaTime);

else

targetScale = Mathf.Lerp(currentScale, fogData.ValueRO.TargetScale, fogData.ValueRO.LerpSpeed * SystemAPI.Time.DeltaTime);

localTransform.ValueRW = localTransform.ValueRO.WithScale(targetScale);

}*/

FogParticleJob fogParticleJob = new FogParticleJob

{

deltaTime = SystemAPI.Time.DeltaTime

};

fogParticleJob.ScheduleParallel();

}

[BurstCompile]

public partial struct FogParticleJob : IJobEntity

{

public float deltaTime;

public void Execute(ref LocalTransform localTransform, in FogData fogData)

{

float currentScale = localTransform.Scale;

float targetScale;

if (Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(localTransform.Position.x, localTransform.Position.y), fogData.PlayerPosition) <= distThreshold)

targetScale = Mathf.Lerp(currentScale, 0, fogData.LerpSpeed * deltaTime);

else

targetScale = Mathf.Lerp(currentScale, fogData.TargetScale, fogData.LerpSpeed * deltaTime);

localTransform = localTransform.WithScale(targetScale);

}

}

}


It becomes an entity.  The game object gets destroyed.  It is more like a prefab.  There are a lot of courses on dots and entities and it is a very different way of thinking
